# Close http connection after web service call, in Android

Tags: android, web-services, http, ksoap2

How can I close connection opened by the following code:

```
 HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL)
 androidHttpTransport.call(soap_action, envelope);
```

HttpTransportSE is a class defined in Ksoap2 library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if(httpTransport!=null){
            httpTransport.reset();
            try {
                httpTransport.getConnection().disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
androidHttpTransport.reset();
```

?

See [here](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/doc/api/org/ksoap2/transport/Transport.html#reset%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Cancel the AsyncTask inside which you are creating the connection as the cancelled AsyncTask will stop all the processes running inside it and hence your connection would get closed too.

**`mAsyncTask.cancel(true);`**

Comment: I'm not using AsyncTask. I'm calling web service from Service Android

Comment: I can stop the Service...but I'm not sure the connection will be closed!

Comment: You connection would get closed once the thread it is running on stops. So, I think it would work.

Comment: Maybe is an IIS problem? I have 1 call every 20 seconds! Initially all works good, but after a few hours an error occurs (exhaust poll connection) , and cleaning the connection pool on IIS the application works fine again.

Comment: Oh, okay. I am not an expert on this, but yeah most probably an IIS problem.